# Java compiler infinite loop (problem with generics)

Tags: java, spring, generics, compiler-errors, stack-overflow

I have Spring java project that uses looped generics structure:

```
abstract class BaseA<T extends BaseB<?>> {}
abstract class BaseB<T extends BaseA<?>> {}

class AImpl extends BaseA<BImpl> {}
class BImpl extends BaseB<AImpl> {}
```

which creates compiler infinite loop:

> An exception has occurred in the compiler (15.0.1). Please file a bug
> against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page
> (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Datab
> ase (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java
> compiler in your report. Thank you.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4731)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4733)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4733)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4733)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4733)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4733)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4733)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4733)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4733)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1685)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4701)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitClassType(Types.java:4686)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1010)
> at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4942)

The wired thing is that I can compile and run project using InteliJ IDEA with eclipse compiler and I'm wondering how could I package it to jar because `mvn compile` throws this error.

- I found some simillar error there: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218030

Comment: Seems like JDK issue, have you tried with JDK14 or any other?

Comment: Yeah I tried JDK17

Comment: both oracle jdk and open jdk 17

Comment: I would advise you not to use the latest JDK, latest never means stable, one version before is the best course of action, that way you can deduct if the issue is with JDK or with your code, but I am 90% sure it is an issue of JDK bug, it takes time for everything to be flushed.